# Value Pass from Python to EXE

Tags: c++, python-3.x

Actually I create ".exe" file using C++ that takes 1 value as input and calculate the result. Now i want to pass the value form a python program to the ".exe" directly. Is is actually possible??

Comment: How does the exe get the input?  Does it prompt the user, command line argument, divide the position of the sun by the temperature of room plus the operators age?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is output the python program to a file. From the console it looks like:

```
$ python script.py > output
```

or you can do it in Python by redirecting `stdout` to file:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('output', 'w')
```

Then you can use the output file as input to your exe.

```
$ program.exe output
```

Comment: Is there any way to solve this without using any kind of output file?

Comment: Actually i think file I/O slow down the process speed